# Largest positive integer which can be represented in Julia using Float64

Tags: floating-point, julia

I am trying to view the bitstring of the largest positive integer that can be exactly represented using Julia. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) says that 2^1024 * (1-2^(-53)) is the integer. However, when I try using Julia, the bitstring is all zeros.

```
julia> bitstring(Float64( 2^1024  - 2^971  ))
"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
```

The bitstring I am expecting is

```
0 11111111110 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

Can you please help me clarify why this discrepancy happens?

Comment: `2^1024` looks like a pure integer operation. Does Julia have unbounded integers? If not, I'd expect both `2^1024` and `2^971` to wrap to `0`. See https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/#Overflow-behavior

Comment: Try something like `Float64(2^53-1) * (Float64(2) ^ Float64(971))` (I'm sure there are more efficient ways, but I'm no Julia expert).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those powers of integers overflow to zero integers before becoming floats.  You can work in `BigInt`, though:

```
julia> 2^1024  - 2^971
0

julia> big"2"^1024  - big"2"^971
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368

julia> Float64(big"2"^1024  - big"2"^971)
1.7976931348623157e308

julia> bitstring(ans)
"0111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

Or alternatively convert the input integers to floats already.

Answer (score 9):

`2^1024 - 2^971` overflows before you convert to `Float64`. Instead you can do

```
julia> bitstring(prevfloat(typemax(Float64)))
 "0111111111101111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

There are a few advantages over the `big` approach: You don't have to know what the max representable value is -- 2^1024 - 2^971; it works for many different types (you could do the same with `Float32`, etc); and it's faster.

For integer type `T` you would do

```
bitstring(typemax(T))
```

The reason for using `prevfloat` with floats, is that `typemax(Float64)` is `Inf`;

Comment: or `Float64(big(2)^1024  - big(2)^971)` to avoid an overflow by using `BigInt`.